# Constructor cannot be applied to given types Timer

Tags: java, timer, arguments, actionlistener, schedule

It says

> constructor Timer in class Timer cannot be applied to given types.
>   required:int, ActionListener.
>  found:no arguments.
> reason: actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length.

and

> cannot find symbol. symbol:
>   method scheduleAtFixedRate

```
private void initBoard() {
  addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
  setFocusable(true);

  bricks = new Brick[N_OF_BRICKS];
  setDoubleBuffered(true);
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), DELAY, PERIOD);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the import you used for the `Timer` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you imported the `Timer` class from `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer`.

You need the following statement in the beginning of your file:

```
import java.util.Timer;
```